# setup.py Not Found When Trying To Install YouCompleteMe

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, vim, youcompleteme, vundle

When i try to run:

```
python3 install.py --all
```

For a while it loads things but then i get:

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Failed to build watchdog module.
```

My Install is a fresh minimal install of Ubuntu 20.04, so far i've tried:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install python3-dev
pip3 install setuptools
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

I also saw, that i should run this, from where the "setup.py" file is but i cannot find that also

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Did you actually download YouCompleteMe first? You run the `python3 install.py` command from within the directory you downloaded it to. Notice the instructions [here](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#linux-64-bit). See how the commands go:

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
python3 install.py --all
```

The first `cd` command goes to the directory that it assumes you downloaded the plugin to.

Comment: Yes i did install it with vundle, and i seem to have all the files required.

Comment: You said you couldn't find the `setup.py` file in your question. So if you found it, run the command in the same directory.

Comment: No i did not find it, but my files at `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe` match the ones found on their github page, but their github page  also misses `setup.py`

Comment: Problem Solved!

I tried reinstalling YouCompleteMe several time, following a guide on how to uninstall on Vundle, but they didn't tell me that after deleting the plugin from `.vimrc` you also have to manually remove the folder `~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe` , after that the installation was a succes, thank you for your time!